# Setting the year range for jQuery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker, and I want to set the year range. This is my code:

```
$( "#birthday" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-100:-10"
});
```

It loads and becomes unresponsive until both year and month drop down items are selected. What am I doing wrong in above code?

Comment: looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Hgvq5/1/

Comment: no it won't looks fine. As clicked on navigation arrow marks for month change, after December year won't update. And also it wont select year as set in drop down box. Every time it selects 2013 as present year.